# Push notifications doesn't work after approving in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, push-notification

After I had lost more than a day while searching for solution, I decided to ask here for advise.

So, I have an iPhone app that use PN, and I have server with installed Easy APNS module. Easy APNS is a bit modified for my needs, but still.
I expected that there could be a problems with PN after distributing my app and i tried to avoid it. I studied a lot of papers. But now I have problems.

As at most of similar questions, everything worked fine in development mode, but in production mode app doesn't receive notifications.

When I've tested my app, fixed bugs, checked my server in development mode, using sandbox apple server, I went to submitting my app for review. According to manuals, I've done:
- enabled production pushes for my AppId
- generated distribution provision for AppStore
- uploaded and installed both certificate and provision
- APS certificate and key in keyChain I've exported to .pem ssl certificate like described here: http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/
- I've uploaded certificate to my server
- built my source using Archive scheme with release configuration. Of course, I've used distribution provision

Than I've submitted binary for review and when it was approved, I've installed it on iPhone from AppStore. And now I can't receive push. Nor on my test device, nor any other.

Till now I've:
- regenerated pem certificate.
- tried to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com/ using this cert - connection OK (connection to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/ with the same cert was rejected).
- checked provision file - key aps-environment is set to production
- checked manuals if I had to change something in source before submitting - nothing.

Actually, devices are registering on server after being launched. They are receiving device token and retrieving it to server with all additional information - all seems to be correct.
Server seems be sending messages correct too - using correct cert file, connecting to 2195 port of gateway.push.apple.com, having no any problems with creating connection and sending message, and receive no any feedback.

So, both device and server can connect to APNS, but server can't send message through it.

I saw a lot of similar problems and a lot of possible solutions. But none of them was helpful.
But I will be thankful for any help, ideas or advice.

Answer (score 0):

Heh... Seems that problem was that my web-developer switched production and developing certificates... Rather silly...

But now I know a lot about Push-notifications)

Thanks a lot StackOverflow!

Comment: Could you help me? , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840431/push-message-doesnt-send-using-with-distributed-certificate