# Push message doesn't send using with distributed certificate

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

I can send push notification with developer p12 file using with sandbox, but my application on the appstore, I use distribution certificate f12 file using with gateway.push.apple.com messages cannot reach to devices.

Push notification service activated on distirbuted certificate, I checked on developer.apple.com, I'm also trying new device id. (not developer device id)

How can i solve my problem? Could you help me? where is my wrong?

My C# code like below:

int port = 2195;

```
    String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";

    String certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("distribution.p12");


    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), "xxx", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
    try
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw (e);
        client.Close();
        return;
    }
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
    writer.Write((byte)0); 
    writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
    writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)
    //String deviceID = "f1430c99 910d292d 2f756294 f2f6b348 153bc215 d5404447 16b294eb fdb9496c";
    writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
    String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + Mesaj + "\",\"badge\":0,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
    writer.Write((byte)0);
    writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
    byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    writer.Write(b1);
    writer.Flush();
    byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
    sslStream.Write(array);
    sslStream.Flush();
    client.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try to send the message from a local machine of from your server? If from your server, perhaps your server blocks port 2195.

Comment: if the port is close, i cannot send message to sandbox, but message arrive if i send from sandbox.

Comment: Is there anyone who can help?